# Should we exclude extremely underpaying ads from Jobs?

Tags: discussion

Coming across a SO ad for a job like this https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/81540/front-end-css-styling-and-drupal-themeing-compucorp?sec=False I remembered that I have seen (especially from London or England in General) a lot of ads for jobs which I can only describe as unethical and extremely underpaid.

Shockingly, I googled the wage for programmers in London and found out that it is really quite low (given the high cost of living), but ads for a full-time position for 25k pounds (as the highest possible!) seem just wrong to me. I would actually expect the cleaning staff to get paid more than this.

Yes, I know this position is offered remotely, but still it seems like a low-balling offer. In the end, encouraging such ads only enables employers to offshore labour to low-cost regions and decreasing local wages.

Shouldn't we maybe restrict ads to the ones which offer at least a sensible minimum pay, e.g. maybe a junior salary for the local market for this position minus 20% as an absolute minimum. As far as I understand SO markets the Jobs especially as a high-value target and I think no one wants to waste their time with jobs with a ridiculous compensation, so this would also be a way to improve the ads.

Comment: It is listed as a remote job - so presumably you wouldn't actually *have* to live in London.

Comment: @Shog9 ... I especially mentioned in my question that I read that this job is posted as remote. I feel like you haven't read my question thoroughly.

Comment: I'm just not sure what your question *is*, @dirkk. The job doesn't seem to require living in London, but you're concerned it's a poor wage by London's standards; so what? I work for a company in NYC, and there's zero chance I could afford to live in NYC on what I make... But I *don't* live in NYC. So what's a local wage when there's no fixed location?

Comment: Unethical is offering an interesting job with decent pay,then swapping it for less than cleaning money. Happened to me once. If they're clearly up front about how much they're willing to offer, folk should be able to make a decision. Also, arn't london living costs cray cray, and most people live outside?

Comment: I think it should be the decision of the market. Although the purely free market has also a lot of negative side-effects, too. Well... then decide the SE Inc. :-)

Comment: @Shog9 Maybe my example ad is just not the best one. I also saw non-remote job offers recently with a quite low salary. So my question is not about this specific job ad, it is in general: Should we have some standard (and we then can agree about the standard; you seem to not be concerned about remote jobs; I am. So we could discuss this - later) salary expectations for Jobs?

Comment: @Close Voters: I really don't see why this question should be closes as off topic, because it only applies to a certain site. As far as I can see Jobs has no separate Meta, so what would be the place to ask this?

Comment: Ah, I see now "Stack Overflow Careers (Employers). Questions for Stack Overflow Jobs should go to Stack Overflow Meta". Don't know why, but seems like this is the way to go. Ok, so can this question be moved or am I supposed to cross-post this?

Comment: Bad news, Cleaners make *considerably less* than £25K/yr. Nurses in London barely scrape in that either.

Answer (score 6):

I've had some pretty terrible paying jobs that I rather liked. A job is about more than just money.
This particular job ad has a focus on "Art Galleries, Non-Profits and Charities"; it goes on to explain that "our clients include Charities such as Wikimedia, Amnesty and Farm Africa, galleries such as the Photographers Gallery and Craft Central but we’ve got a long client list that includes other companies, trade associations and government bodies".

I would expect Stack Overflow jobs to make some basic quality checks: is this a real company, is the ad reasonably comprehensible, is this actually for a programmer(-ish) position, and so forth.
What I *don't* expect them to do is to make judgement calls about what kind of job I want; that's your own choice. You consider this ad a time-waster? That's okay, but other people might disagree. Stack Overflow jobs does a pretty good job at filtering out useless noise, but in the end at least part of the "noise" is just "personal preference" (e.g. every PHP ad would be "noise" to me).

---

> I would actually expect the cleaning staff to get paid more than this.

The minimum wage is [about £15,000](https://www.gov.uk/national-minimum-wage-rates). Even less if you're younger than 25. I'd expect that most cleaners earn the minimum wage and not a whole lot more. The same would apply for many workers in retail, waiters, etc. etc.

Also note that this ad is *not* for a programming position, it's for designing CSS/HTML themes, which is not quite the same thing. I don't know what *exactly* the going rate is for that, but it's almost certainly lower than for a "real" programming position.